# Jasper report Serial no generation in Struts 2 framework

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports

I am working in Struts 2 framework. I want to generate auto increment serial no in jasper report,the report is generated from action page, without a Jsp page. Any help?

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful?  http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/501426/auto-number